# A $10$ digit number with distinct digits such that the following holds:

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

> A $10$ digit number with distinct digits is given and using all of its digits two new numbers are created. The sum of the two new numbers is $99999$ and their product is the same as the $10$ digit number.

Our aim is to find the number.

$\underline{\text{My  Observations:}}$

Note that since the sum of the two new numbers is $99999$, we can pair two digits in the following way for their sum to be 9: $$0+9,1+8,2+7,3+6,4+5$$ The new numbers created must consist of 5 digits.

Comment: How are the two numbers created. Do you divide the 10-digit one somewhere, or can you change the order of the digits

Comment: if I don't get it wrong, then it is equivalent to solving $(99999 - x) x = 100000x + 99999 - x$

Comment: @LearningMathematics, the original number needn't be cut into half. Any five digits can be taken. Otherwise the quadratic will have an integral solution.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a downvote in the question!

Comment: then I found $47931*52068=2495671308$ using a computer

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it is unclear what options there are in forming the two new numbers. Sounds like two 5-digit numbers are intended, but what constraints are there? Will the digits need to be in the original order? What else?